# How to list objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

Is there a list of objects in JavaScript? I have a query that is pulling in 2 items for each record (name and date).

In c# I would write some code that would create a list of objects, the list would have 2 objects (myName and myDate).

Basically I would like each item in an array or list to have 2 objects in it (myName and myDate).

Is this possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Don't use the variable names of myName and myDate. Use something more meaningful than that.

Comment: @code is it you want two objects in each element of array or one object with two fields in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you define an object in javascript much like a c# anonymous object

```
var myObj = {
         name: 'John Smith',
         date: '2015-05-21'
};
```

You can put these in an array

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an array of javascript objects. The notation for this would be as follows:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{myName: "Name 1", myDate: "Date 1"}, {myName: "Name 2", myDate: "Date 2"}]
```

I would recommend looking at some examples of [Javascript objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp), and then seeing how you could build your desired structure programmatically.